# True tone and night shift not working after updating MacOS from 14.3 to 14.4

Tags: display, night-shift

I have this very annoying problem after doing the minor version upgrade of MacOS (14.3 to 14.4). After restarting the machine, the color profile was very different on my external monitor (HP U32 4K) and at first I couldn't figure out what was wrong and why the whites have a harsh blue tint. After looking at the settings of the monitor and macOS, I realised that the issue was actually True Tone not working on my external monitor. In addition, Night shift is also not working on the external monitor.

Things I've tried:

- restarting / shutdown / unplugging the usb-c cable and using a different cable (hdmi to usb-c)
- trying out all colour profiles in the display section of the macbook and external monitor
- factory reset on the monitor
- setting the external monitor as primary / mirror
- changing privacy and security of the

Nothing seems to work. As far as I'm aware (please correct me if I'm wrong), the true tone option is the OS changing the current profile / white points of the extenal monitor. In this case for whatever reason the OS is not doing it, does anyone have any clue how to fix it? Thanks!

Edit:

I've tried it with the following monitors, and True tone / night shift works fine:

- An older NEC 24" monitor
- A Dell monitor (34" ultrawide)
- LG ultrafine 27" 4K